# Characterizations of groups whose general linear representations are all trivial

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, algebraic-groups, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. Suppose for any general linear representation $\rho:G\to\mathrm{GL}(n)$,
$\rho$ must be trivial.

Question: Are there any characterizations or equivalent conditions for $G$?

Thanks for guidance.

Comment: If $G$ is finitely generated, then this is equivalent to having no finite quotients by Malcev's theorem. E.g. Higman's group. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higman_group

Comment: Without quantifiers on $n$ the question is ambiguous, the question being meaningful when $n$ is fixed. If interpreted as "no non-trivial representation for any $n$" indeed for finitely generated groups it means that there is no nontrivial finite quotient (as far as I know, $\{1\}$ is a finite quotient). Of course no need to exclude the trivial group in the question as well.

Comment: I should also add that the answer may depend on the field too (or means: for every field? for every field of characteristic 0?).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With no limit on $n$, Martin Bridson and I proved that this property is undecidable for finitely presented groups. See the reformulation of the main theorem on page 2 of [Bridson and Wilton - The triviality problem for profinite completions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.2273):

> There  is  no  algorithm  that  can  determine  whether  or  not  a finitely presented group has a non-trivial finite-dimensional linear representation  (over  any  field).

This reformulation goes as Ian Agol mentions in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376943/characterizations-of-groups-whose-general-linear-representations-are-all-trivial#comment956001_376943): every representation is trivial if and only if the group has no non-trivial finite quotients.

On the other hand, for fixed $n$ such problems are decidable.  See, for instance, [Algorithms determining finite simple images of finitely presented groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.07183) by Bridson, Evans, Liebeck, and Segal.